# What could be the factors of $-9m⁴+12m³+14m²-12m-5$

Tags: factoring

$-9m⁴+12m³+14m²-12m-5$. The question has been asked in iit genius exam of fitjee and is of class 8 level. We have to find all possible roots.

Comment: The usual first step is to look for rational roots.

Comment: Hint: $m=1$ is a root.

Comment: We only need to test for divisors of $9$ and $5$, see the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) we find the rational roots $m=\pm 1,-\frac{1}{3},\frac{5}{3}$, so that
$$
-9m^4+12m^3+14m^2-12m-5= - (3m + 1)(3m - 5)(m + 1)(m - 1).
$$