# What's the need to find derivative of a polynomial?

Tags: calculus

I was learning differential calculus when I came with a doubt that why do we need to find derivative of polynomial. How is it useful?

Comment: I'm sure the text you are using contains many applications, have you looked at those?

Comment: They are used to calculate instantaneous rate of change of something with respect to something else.

Comment: They are used almost everywhere, e.g., also for algebraic field extensions with minimal polynomials. One computes $gcd(f,f')$ for example. You have used already some polynomial in a similar algebraic context, see your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546476/what-could-be-the-factors-of-9m⁴12m³14m²-12m-5).

Comment: Eg- velocity in velocity time graph

Comment: Your question has been answered previously. Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160821/what-is-the-use-of-derivatives

Comment: if a polynomial has a multiple root, its derivative also shares that root

Comment: Yes, so the gcd of $f$ and $f'$ then is non-trivial.

Comment: What about polynomials themselves. Do you see any need ?

Comment: @amd : this reference has already been given by Aniket Gupta. Besides, I have given an example which is not in this reference.

Comment: @JeanMarie I didn’t simply give a reference. I voted to close as a duplicate. That comment is automatically generated by the vote.

Comment: @amd Sorry for my remark. I hadn't thought to this connection.

Answer (score 2):

An example one can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/743223), but in a simplified presentation.

Suppose we have a have two walls at right angle and we want to delimitate a rectangular area with a $3$ meters long barbed wire fence, knowing that 2 sides of the rectangle are along the wall.

Our objective is to maximize the enclosed area.

Let us denote by $x$ the length in one direction ; therefore, the length in the other direction is  $(3-x)$.

A) **First approach using polynomial derivation in a blind way :**.
 The area of a rectangle being length $\times$ width, we have to maximize the following function :

$$f(x):=x(3-x)=3x-x^2$$

which will be obtained for the value of $x$ such that $f'(x)=0$ giving $3-2x=0$, i.e., $x=3/2$.

Please note that we are finding that the square is the most advantageous among all rectangular shapes.

B) **Second approach, of a geometrical nature.** Consider the figure below :

[image]

Extending the length of the fence on the horizontal direction from $x$ to $x+dx$ brings a correlative decrease from $(3-x)$ to $3-x-dx$ in the other direction. Therefore, we have an area gain of $(3-x)dx$ and an area loss of $x dx$. The net gain is :

$$Gain - Loss = (3-x)dx - x dx=\underbrace{(3-2x)}_{f'(x)}dx$$

Expressing that there is an equilibrium (Gain=Loss) is like saying that $f'(x)=0$ !

Moreover, the second order element $dx^2$ which is neglected is vizualized as the small pale blue little square at the upper right corner, reflecting the expansion of :

> $$\underbrace{(x+dx)(3-x-dx)}_{f(x+dx)}=\underbrace{x(3-x)}_{f(x)}+\underbrace{(3-x-x)}_{f'(x)}dx-\underbrace{dx^2}_{\text{neglected}}$$

which is a Taylor expansion of function  $f$. This expansion proves in particular that :

$$\dfrac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}=f'(x)-dx$$

Comment: (+1) , Nice and practical.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\i{\mathbf{i}}$

One of the beautiful and somewhat unexpected
application of the derivative of a polynomial
is  [Marden’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem),
gives a geometric relationship between the zeros 
of a third-degree polynomial with complex coefficients and the
zeros of its derivative.

Suppose the zeroes $z_1,\ z_2$, and $z_3$ 
of a third-degree polynomial 
$p(z)$ are non-collinear. 
There is a unique
ellipse inscribed in the triangle with vertices 
$z_1,\ z_2,\ z_3$ and tangent to the sides at their midpoints: 
the [Steiner inellipse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerInellipse.html). 
The foci $F_1,\ F_2$ of that ellipse 
are the zeros of the derivative $p'(z)$.

\begin{align}
F_{1,2}&=\tfrac13\,\left(z_1+z_2+z_3
\pm\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2-z_1\cdot z_2-z_2\cdot z_3-z_3\cdot z_1}\right)
\end{align}

For example, consider a triangle with vertices

\begin{align}
z_1&=0
,\quad
z_2=10
,\quad
z_3=10+8\,\i
,\\
p(z)&=
(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)
=z^3-(20+8\,\i)\,z^2+(100+80\,\i)\,z
,\\
p'(z)&=
3\,z^2-(40+16\,\i)\,z+100+80\,\i
=0
,\\
F_1&=\tfrac13\,\left(20+\sqrt{2\,\sqrt{481}+18}
+\i\,\left(8+\sqrt{2\,\sqrt{481}-18}\right)\right)
\approx 9.288443511+4.361869847\,\i
,\\
F_2&=\tfrac13\,\left(20-\sqrt{2\,\sqrt{481}+18}
+\i\,\left(8-\sqrt{2\,\sqrt{481}-18}\right)\right)
\approx 4.044889823+0.971463487\,\i
.
\end{align}

[image]

$\endgroup$

Comment: pretty result, connected to polynomials indeed, but difficult to catch for a beginner...

Comment: I have written another example.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative in any case can be useful in many ways. The most obvious comparison is if you are given a continuous function to represent displacement ($s$) then we can calculate velocity and acceleration by differentiating with respect to time:
$$v=\frac{ds}{dt},a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}$$
However often other problems require finding the optimum conditions for something to happen, which is represented as a maxima or minima on a graph and hence finding the derivative is used here too.

Comment: The question is specifically for polynomials. Your answer is too general.

Comment: Yes but it still applies to polynomials, I am just stating that derivates in general also have many uses

Comment: Yes, this is fine. But the main point of the question is ( I believe) not derivatives in general but why it is in particular interesting for polynomials.

Comment: That is true but there are very few cases where derivates apply solely to polynomials